# unity3d - delete file causes "attempt to write a readonly database UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()"

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine

I created a project in Unity, work a little bit on it. And then I tried to delete one of the scripts I created earlier, but every time I try to delete it a message shows up:

> **Fatal Error!**
>
> attempt to write a readonly database
> UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()

I tried to delete the file manually from the folder, but it caused similar error every time I launched Unity.

All the googling did not help me as long as all the answers are for the Windows, where permissions are easy to set up. For OS X only one answer was found, which said to make a folder shared, which also didn't help.

Does anyone know the solution of that?

Answer (score 1):

I get this crash whenever I am trying to delete a file from my project or trying to create a build in unity.  I am using a mac running sierra OSX (though I expect that won't matter) but the primary issue, is due to limited internal hard drive space, I had the project saved on an external SSD drive plugged into my mac.  This seems to be the main issue.  If your running into this issue and you have a similar setup, try copying the project file over to your onboard hard drive and operating it from there.

I have not yet found another solution around this problem.  For some reason unity can save to external drives fine, but doesn't like to delete or build from them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete all in folder
/Users/Shared/Unity/4.0_Angrybots/Temp

Comment: I do not have such a folder "Unity" in /Users/Shared

Comment: I guess he tried to inform you to delete your project Temp directory. I'll suggest you to execute a "Reimport All" from unity editor's menu first and if didn't solve try to delete Temp and also Library from your system.